# Why is Meteor duplicating database objects after a refresh?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm building a test app, my first one as I learn to program, so please forgive me if my terminology is off.

I'm running Meteor release 0.6.6.3 in Chromium browser version 30.0.1599.114

I have fake products added to a collection as seen in the code below.  However for some reason when I refresh the browser, or after a server restart, each product is duplicated in the browser so  it then shows two hammers, two wrenches, etc..  The only way I've been able to fix this is by manually deleting the products from the database.

I don't see any issues with my code so does this have something to do with Meteor?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JS code:

```
var Products = new Meteor.Collection("Products");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

window.Products = Products;

Products.insert({Name : "Hammer", Price : 4.50, InStock : true});
Products.insert({Name : "Wrench", Price : 2.70, InStock : true});
Products.insert({Name : "Screw Driver", Price : 3.00, InStock : false});
Products.insert({Name : "Drill", Price : 5.25, InStock : true});

 Template.Products.ProductArr = function(){
   return Products.find({}, {sort: {Name: 1}});
};

Template.Products.events = {
   "click .Product" : function(){
      if(this.InStock)
         confirm("Would you like to buy a " + this.Name + " for " + this.Price + "$");
      else
         alert("That item is not in stock");
   }
};
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

HTML is below, just a simple template.

```
<head>
  <title>Products</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> Products}}
</body>

<template name="Products">
   {{#each ProductArr}}
      <div class="Product">
         <h2>{{Name}}</h2>
         <p>Price: ${{Price}}</p>
         {{#if this.InStock}}
            <p>This Item is in stock</p>
         {{else}}
            <p>This Item is currently sold out</p>
         {{/if}}
      </div>
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Meteor is doing exactly what you are telling it to: insert new Products when a page is loaded. If you want this to happen only if the database is empty then you need to add a guard like this:

```
if (Products.find().count() === 0) {
  Products.insert({Name : "Hammer", Price : 4.50, InStock : true});
  Products.insert({Name : "Wrench", Price : 2.70, InStock : true});
  Products.insert({Name : "Screw Driver", Price : 3.00, InStock : false});
  Products.insert({Name : "Drill", Price : 5.25, InStock : true});
}
```

Alternatively, you could look into a solution using upsert (http://docs.meteor.com/#upsert), which will only add a new item if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: If that code is executed on the client it must be executed after the client has received all the data, since otherwise, the client will think the Products collection is empty, although there exists some documents in the collection the client isn't aware of yet.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.  Upsert looks interesting as well so I might try that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

On the first line you ask Meteor to create a Mongo Document on Server, and available on client using automatic pub/sub.

Then, on the client you ask Meteor to insert 4 products. So Meteor create them locally on client side, and then it syncs with the server. So they are created on the server.

If you refresh, then Meteor will create them again, on client and then on server.
And if you refresh again and again, it will insert as many times you refresh.

You can do what is suggested by @ChristianF : check if you have documents, and then insert them if you have not.
Personaly, i would do the check and insertion on the server side, it's more secure for the future as you should remove autopublish and insecure packages.